# Jmeter with CSV file - approach thread group by row in CSV

Tags: csv, jmeter

I have a test plan with 6 thread group.
I want to create data parameters using csv file.
My question is can I create in the csv column with threadgroup number and Jmeter will be smart and get the data for the specific thread group?. I want to create testplan with couple scenarios (thread groups), and to approach via csv. 
is it can be done?

[[image]][example of what I want to create]

Comment: have CSV per thread group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way which I am able to do something like this is to use "IF Controller".

I have put an If controller under each thread group and checking if "ThreadG" value is matching from the csv.

[image]

[image]

Although, I personally prefer to use 3 separate csv for each thread group like @Kiril S suggested.
Hope it helps.